# How to ensure something definitely stays in localstorage despite size limit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

I'm writing an app in Angular JS and plan to use local storage for keeping the logged in user details instead of using cookies.

The trouble is that I may want to use local storage at a later date to store other things, like caching search results and other data. I know that an exception is thrown if the browser storage limit is hit and that's not a problem for other data, but if the storage is full and the user logs in then it would fail if the account details couldn't be stored.

Is there an obvious solution here, other than to write a bunch of code that prioritizes what I should delete if the limit is hit and then deleting something less important and trying again?

Comment: Well, if you have page flow why don't you keep that information in the server's session? For a single page app you could just store this information in memory. Otherwise I see no other way than deleting less important content from the storage.

Comment: Storing in memory is not ideal, opening something in a new tab would require a new login. Server is just a RESTful API so should be stateless. I'm storing a JSON web token which I need to pass with each call so I think cookies or localStorage is the way to go. Cookie would be sent in headers each time which would be duplication, so it does seem as if localStorage is the best way.